# Get a cobol DB2 date for a local variable

Tags: db2, cobol

I'm a cobol, trying to extract a current date in DB2, but the EZ01-TIMESTAMP field returns with junk.
This is the definition of the variables:

```
EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA    END-EXEC.
01  EZ01.
       03  EZ01-CURRENT-DATE             PIC S9(8)       COMP-3.
       03  EZ01-TIMESTAMP                PIC X(26).
```

and this is the command:

```
EXEC SQL
    SET :EZ01-TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
END-EXEC
```

sqlcode= -805
if anyone knows anything that can help, please, thanks

Comment: Sqlcode -805 typically indicates "DBRM or package not found in plan". Is there any more specific info in the error messages?

Comment: -805 is package not found. You might not have bound (or rebound) the package properly. Triple-check your build.

Comment: Hey all
I'm sorry, I just returned a version
and I moved the changes slowly, step by step again, I do not know what the problem was
but now it works :)